# SSIS OLEDB Connection Manager error - Unable to create the type with the name 'DTS.ConnectionManagerOleDb.7

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, oledbconnection

I have several SSIS packages created some time ago which read data from one instance of SQL Server and load them to another SQL Server instance, connections have always been OLEDB and has been working fine up until earlier today when I opened one of the packages and all the OLEDB connections are now failing with an error saying 'Unable to create the type with the name 'DTS.ConnectionManagerOleDb.7'.

If I try and create a new OLEDB connection I get the 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' error'.

Have been using Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.9.37 and SSIS 15.0.2000.150, also tried with VS 2019 Community and getting the same error.

I've tried creating a new project and package and get the same error when creating an OLEDB connection manager.

Anyone with any idea what is going on? Was working on one of these packages this morning and it was working fine, since this afternoon it's buggered.

Answer (score 0):

You should do these things:

1. Keep the Current VS Enterprise (5.7.1)
2. Uninstall only your SSDT through VS Installer
3. Current VS Enterprise (5.7.1) with PRIOR SSDT (5.5.2) (You have to install this version to resolve your issue)

[enter link description here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ssisssdt-existing-connection-strings-unable-to-cre/257696)
'ssisssdt-existing-connection-strings-unable-to-cre'